# confusion about using .then .catch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

Am I supposed to use `.then` and `.catch` if I am using async/await? Is the exception handled by async/await or in some cases we have to use `.then` and `.catch`?

*Before using Async/Await*

---

```
message.save()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Saved");
            return Message.findOne({ message: "badword" })
        })
        .then(censored => {
            if (censored) {
                console.log("Censored owrd Found", censored);
                return Message.deleteOne({ _id: censored.id })
            }
            io.emit("message", req.body);
            res.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return console.error(err);
        })
```

*After using Async/Await*

---

````
    await message.save();

    console.log("saved");

    var censored = await Message.findOne({ message: "badword" })

    if (censored)
        await Message.deleteOne({ _id: censored.id })
    else
        io.emit("message", req.body)

    res.sendStatus(200);```
````

Comment: You just use `try...catch` with `async/await`.

Comment: FWIW, your two examples aren't equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Work with try/catch in case you can use async/await. Like this:

```
try {
  await message.save();
  console.log("saved");

  var censored = await Message.findOne({ message: "badword" })

  if (censored)
      await Message.deleteOne({ _id: censored.id })
  else
      io.emit("message", req.body)

  res.sendStatus(200);
} catch (err) {
  res.sendStatus(500);
  console.error(err);
}
```